# Where are the layouts and styles defined for PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, styles, android-view, android-styles

Where (preferably in an online-browsable source repository) is the layout defined for [`PreferenceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html)?  I'd like to copy the different styles for headings, etc.

I see that in `android.preference.PreferenceActivity` there is a reference to `com.android.internal.R.layout.preference_list_content`, but I don't see an `R` directory in  `[android-sdk]\sources\android-15\com\android\internal` in the source downloaded via the SDK.

I assume that other Android layouts are close by in the source tree.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming you want this for the latest version of Android, the for PreferenceActivity itself can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.java).  You can see from there that the layout used is `R.layout.preference_list_content`, which can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/layout/preference_list_content.xml).

If you use Chrome, [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgcbffeicehlpmgmnhnkjbjoldkfhoin) will help you greatly as it will apply a "View Source" link next to every class page in the developer docs.

You might also find the [Github Mirror](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base) helpful if you are looking for versions from an earlier Android release.  I've found the Github interface easier to track back to previous branches and tags.

Comment: Because those are only the framework source files, not the resources.  If you want to see what resources are part of the SDK, you have to unpack the android.jar in the platforms/ directories.  However, in this case you wouldn't find it there either because the layout is not part of the SDK (hence the internal marker).  Best to always use the online repos which have the full AOSP source.